# How to return a value from database to LaravelCollective Dropdown?

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective, laravel-6

My LaravelCollective dropdown doesn't return value as expected right now the dropdown looks like this
[image]

I want that dropdown just return value from `nama` column

This is my Controller

```
public function create()
    {
        $supplierList = Supplier::select('idSupplier', 'nama')->get();
        return view('transactionsIN.create', compact('supplierList'));
    }
```

and this is my LaravelCollective on blade.php page

```
{!! Form::select('id_Supplier',$supplierList, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pilih salah satu supplier...']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop to the array of $supplierList then call

```
{!! Form::select('id_Supplier',$supplierList->pluck('nama'), null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pilih salah satu supplier...']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this one

```
$supplierList = Supplier::select('idSupplier', 'nama')->pluck('nama');
```

Or just simply

```
$supplierList = Supplier::pluck('nama');
```